# Using array parameter in DQL

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I am basically trying to execute dql as below:

```
$queryString = "SELECT ac FROM CloudExchange\Entities\Account ac JOIN ac.account_connections cn WHERE cn.account IN (:accounts)";
$query = $em->createQuery($queryString);
$query->setParameter('accounts', $service->getAccounts());
$results = $query->getResult();
```

I am using doctrine 2.3.x version. Seems like the above approach doesn't work. It returns following error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection could not be converted to string in......
```

Can anyone have any idea what is possibly wrong with my approach or what alternative better way to achieve "WHERE IN" condition based DQL please? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to echo a collection somewhere? Check the line it tells you, see if something is trying to be used as a string

Comment: Thanks for the clue. Actually, I need to make the collection to array as $service->getAccounts()->toArray() and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

OK, just answering my own question, here is the proper way:

```
$queryString = "SELECT ac FROM CloudExchange\Entities\Account ac JOIN ac.account_connections cn WHERE cn.account IN (:accounts)";
$query = $em->createQuery($queryString);
$query->setParameter('accounts', $service->getAccounts()->toArray());
$results = $query->getResult();
```

So, basically I needed to use "$service->getAccounts()->toArray()", collection aren't supported directly inside DQL.